# gcc can't find reference to function DoIt() when linking

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I am currently becoming crazy. It seems like there is a problem with gcc and it <s>can't open include files</s> can't find the function `DoIt()` when linking. I tried compiling this code in code blocks and it didn't work so I tried it with G++ in the console and it still didn't work. So I think it's a problem with gcc.

This is my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "source.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"That works"<<std::endl;
    DoIt();
    while(true)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include "source.h"
#include <iostream>

void DoIt()
{
std::cout<<"That works too"<<std::endl; //Currently doesn't work
}
```

source.h

```
void DoIt();
```

And this is what I wrote in the terminal

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o result
```

This is the error message when i run it

```
/tmp/ccG6X4Bw.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `DoIt()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no clue why it doesn't work

Comment: This is not a problem with the include paths, but an error from the linker telling you that you never defined `DoIt`. You need to provide all `.cpp` files to the compiler command line if you compile and link in one invocation (the default without `-c` on the `g++` command line), so that it has all the definitions.

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o result` does not look like it compiles and links in source.cpp. Give `g++ main.cpp source.cpp -std=c++11 -o result` a shot.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `gcc` will try to compile and link. Linking without the code from `source.cpp` will cause the linker to be unable to link the call of `DoIt` to its code. If you just wish to compile, pass `-c` to `gcc`.

From the man page:

> ```
>   When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking.
>   ...
>    -c  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.
>        The linking stage simply is not done.
> ```